# Why the num of languages in `nltk.corpus` stop words is different depending on the OS?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk

I'm running the same code in two different machines (Mac and Linux) and despite both machines run the same version of `nltk` they offer stop words lists in a different number of languages (14 for Mac, 17 Linux).

```
import nltk
nltk.__version__
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stopwords.ensure_loaded
stopwords_dict = {lang:stopwords.words(lang) for lang in stopwords.__dict__.get('_fileids')}
stopwords_dict.keys()
len(stopwords_dict.keys())
```

Same `nltk` version in both machines `'3.2.5'`, but different number of languages:

**Mac**:

```
dict_keys(['danish', 'dutch', 'english', 'finnish', 'french', 'german', 'hungarian', 'italian', 'norwegian', 'portuguese', 'russian', 'spanish', 'swedish', 'turkish'])

14
```

**Linux**:

```
dict_keys(['kazakh', 'swedish', 'spanish', 'danish', 'english', 'italian', 'portuguese', 'dutch', 'turkish', 'arabic', 'romanian', 'russian', 'french', 'hungarian', 'german', 'finnish', 'norwegian'])
17
```

I unsucessfully tried to find the answer in the `nltk` documentation.

Comment: Update your `nltk_data` on the Mac?

Comment: Ouch! Beautiful, you are totally right `nltk.download("stopwords")` in my case solved it. I forgot nltk data was handled apart. @alvas, can you reply as an answer so we don't leave it as an unanswered question? I know the solution is trivial but it might be helpful to others and this way we keep with the main idea of SO [questions-answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90263/unanswered-question-answered-in-comments).

Comment: Try answering with an answer and make it informative for the next user =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I totally forgot that `nltk` and "the built-in support it offers for dozens of corpora and trained models" are two different things. This explains why even if the `nltk` version is the same the corpora can be different.

As @alvas pointed out in the comments, the solution was just to update the `nltk_data`.

```
 nltk.download("stopwords")
```

Full list of resources that `nltk_data` offers can be found [here](http://www.nltk.org/nltk_data/).